# How can I isolate cells within my ListView row for use with setOnItemClickListener instead of the entire row?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a list of people that I am pulling from the database with a [modified] SimpleCursorAdapter. I then iterate over the cursor and print information out in a ListView in my app. Right now, it is coded so that when I click on a row, my app performs a function. However, what I would like to do is make it so that when I click on an icon within the row, my app will perform the appropriate function.

Where I am having trouble is isolating a cell within the row for the setOnItemClickListener instead of the entire row.

How do I go about isolating an ImageView within the row instead of the entire row itself?

Here is what I have:

**Home.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout studentSwipeRefresh;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
        studentSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.student_swipe_refresh);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        drawTheStudentView();

        studentSwipeRefresh.setColorSchemeColors(Color.parseColor(Constants.RED), Color.parseColor(Constants.ORANGE), Color.parseColor(Constants.YELLOW), Color.parseColor(Constants.GREEN), Color.parseColor(Constants.BLUE), Color.parseColor(Constants.INDIGO), Color.parseColor(Constants.VIOLET));
        studentSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                studentSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                drawTheStudentView();
            }
        });
    }

    private void drawTheStudentView(){
        DatabaseHelper myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        Cursor studentCursor = myDBHelper.getStudentsCursor();
        String[] fromColumns = {"_id","studentID","status","location"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.student_number_textview, R.id.student_id_textview};
        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.student_layout, studentCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        // Replace the _id column with a student count
        mySimpleCursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                String counter = Integer.toString((cursor.getPosition()+1));
                TextView modifiedTextView = (TextView) view;
                if(columnIndex == 0){
                    modifiedTextView.setText(counter);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        ListView myListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.student_row);

        // Listen for somebody clicking on a Student ID, and process
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Cursor subCursor = (Cursor) mySimpleCursorAdapter.getItem(position);
                String zapNumber = subCursor.getString(subCursor.getColumnIndex("studentID"));

                StudentStatus studentStatus = (StudentStatus) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(Constants.TAB_INDEX_PATIENT_VITALS));
                studentStatus.setZapNumber(zapNumber);

                myViewPager.setCurrentItem(Constants.TAB_INDEX_PATIENT_VITALS);
            }
        });

        // Draw the list
        myListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    // Pass me a tab index (see Constants.java) and I'll return a refrence to that tab.
    private String getFragmentTag(int tagID){
        return "android:switcher:" + R.id.pager + ":" + tagID;
    }
}
```

**AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter.java**

```
package myPackage;

public class AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public AlternateRowColorSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.WHITE));
        } else {
            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Constants.LIGHTGREY));
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

**student_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_number_textview"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        style="@style/StudentStyle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/student_id_textview"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        style="@style/StudentStyle" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/student_status_button"
        style="@style/studentIconLink"
        android:src="@drawable/status_icon"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/student_location_button"
        style="@style/studentIconLink"
        android:src="@drawable/location_icon"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility to define a callback interface for communication between the views created in your `Adapter` and your `Fragment`.

Have your `Fragment` implement this interface and pass in a reference to your `Fragment` in your `Adapter`'s constructor. In your `getView()` method in the adapter, you can set an `OnClickListener` on your `ImageView` that you want to listen for, and then trigger the callback you passed into your `Adapter`. Note: you can pass back something like `position` in this callback so you know which row's `ImageView` was selected.